# How to convert a number input so the first two numbers become decimals with oninput

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

This may have been answered already, but I can't find it. I am making a form with a number input that will be used to submit an item price (with two decimal places). I want this to be done without having to manually enter the decimal. ideally with some oninput inline javascript. I was playing with the math function but am still new to javascript and am having no luck.

If you enter 1 it should automatically become 0.01

... or 12 becomes 0.12

... 123 becomes 1.23 etc.

Thanks for any help!

```
<input type=number min=0.00 max=100.00 step=0.01 class='detailsInput' id='priceEntry' name='priceEntry' placeholder='Enter Price' oninput='(Math.round(priceEntry*100)/100)(this)'>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take the "actual value" of the input. Make sure to remove any decimal dot.... Parse it as an integer and divide by 100. Return. ;)

```js
document.querySelector(".detailsInput").addEventListener("input", function(e){
  let actualValue = e.target.value.replace(".","")
  e.target.value=parseInt(actualValue)/100
})
```

```html
<input type=number min=0.00 max=100.00 step=0.01 class='detailsInput' id='priceEntry' name='priceEntry' placeholder='Enter Price'>
```

===
Ho! If you insist on an inline version:

```html
<input type=number min=0.00 max=100.00 step=0.01 class='detailsInput' id='priceEntry' name='priceEntry' placeholder='Enter Price' oninput="this.value=parseInt(this.value.replace('.',''))/100">
```

Comment: thank you for the help! The inline version works great!

Comment: Great! But I would go for an event listener that could handle many inputs... Your call. ;)

Comment: ```this``` popped up in my SO timeline!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, **congrats** on your first contribution.

secondly, **you can achieve that using dataset** because you need to save the user input in some place first then executing any kind of filter on it ...

***here*** : i executed the filter on the dataset .. but there might be alot of better ways for UX -if you don't mind using a script tag.

[see the example on Codepen](https://codepen.io/amans199/pen/wvWErqB)

```js
function explainerHandler(){
  const inputVal = document.querySelector('input').dataset.value

document.querySelector('.input_val').textContent = inputVal
}
```

```html
<input onkeyup="explainerHandler()" type="number" oninput="let val =this.value;this.dataset.value=val/100;" data-value="0"  />
<p class="input_val"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You specifically asked for an **in-line** JavaScript solution. ("*ideally with some oninput inline javascript.*")

You were very close. Using `oninput` means your code will fire every time the input field is modified. So note the change to `onchange` instead. This will wait until you are finished editing the field (your can also use `onblur`).

So the simple algorithm is:

`this.value /= 100`

That needs to be placed inside an executable function expression:

`()=>this.value /= 100`

And as you clearly understand, that must be passed with a function wrapper (or IIFE as you used):

`(()=>this.value /=100)()`

NOTE: You probably realize that using in-line JavaScript is discouraged for many reasons. That is why you will find answers here that encourage you to use JavaScript in other ways.

```html
<input type=number min=0.00 max=100.00 step=0.01 class='detailsInput' id='priceEntry' name='priceEntry' placeholder='Enter Price' onchange='(()=>this.value /= 100)()'>
```

Comment: Try this on your snippet... Input 123. Blur. Try to modify the input now and blur again. ;)

Comment: Works perfectly. What do you see?

Comment: I see 0.01234 when I add a 4 on second blur.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette  So the second time, when `1.23` is in the input, you added a `4` like this: `1.234`? That wasn't the requirement. You're trolling around trying to make the other answers wrong rather than focusing on the requirement. But that's ok, I don't mind validating my answer. So thanks for that!

Comment: I am not trolling around. If another answer is better than my I would upvote it. I comment here just to help you help others. ;) Don't take it bad.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette  I can assume all day long about what may or may not be done with this code by the users, developers, businesses, elephants... The point of these questions is answer them as they are written. It didn't take long for me to figure out that my assumptions about these questions are irrelevant. For instance - I don't ever advocate in-line JavaScript - but I won't make assumptions about _why_ the OP has asked for this.

Comment: But they really prefer PachydermScript. Reachyderm is so slow though! :-)

Answer (score 0):

*This is not using an `oninput` tag option, but a JS option within a script. Perhaps it will help you or others with a similar issue...*

You could use Intl.NumberFormat with an eventlistener. See [MOZILLA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) for more information.

```js
let price = document.getElementById('priceEntry');
let display = document.getElementById('display');
let format = document.getElementById('format');

var currency = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
});

format.addEventListener('click', function() {
  // check to see if value is decimal, if not, divide by 100 to make a decimal else format using formatter
  price.value.indexOf(".") == -1 ? display.textContent = currency.format(price.value / 100) : display.textContent = currency.format(price.value);
})
```

```html
<input type='number' min=0.00 max=100.00 step=0.01 class='detailsInput' id='priceEntry' name='priceEntry' placeholder='Enter Price'><button id="format">format</button>

<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Inputting 123 makes 123.00$... Not 1.23$ ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette thanks for pointing that out, edited eventhandler with conditional.